# Windows Mobile 6 emulator internet connection issue

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-emulator

I am trying to connect Windows Mobile 6 emulator (visual studio 2008) to internet. After couple of hours I got it connected to internet. Now it is showing connected but when I try to browse any site like google.com it is giving popup message that "The page cannot be displayed or downloaded because the connection was lost. Check the connection and try again". I am using Wifi connection in my PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered with the same problem. I disabled my antivirus and it resolved. Try to to connect after you disable your antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide the details on how you set the conection of the emulator!

In the past it was possible to have a virtual network card in the host PC that enabled to setup the emulator with a virtual NE2000 network card. But this was only supported up to WinXP.

Now we have to use ActiveSync/WMDC and dock the emulated Windows Mobile device. Then we can use the WMDC Passthru connection. You have to enable "Allow data connections when docked" and select "This PC is connected to 'internet'" inside the connection settings of WMDC when the emulator is connected.